# Convert Array of NSData to data type that can be played through AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm currently working on an iOS App that uses Bluetooth microphone to capture audio and play it back. The bluetooth microphone sends small 20 byte NSData to the iOS Device constantly.

How can I take those 20 byte NSDatas to playback in AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: Did u get the answer